# how to make the Fragment/Activity not go to the backgoround

Tags: java, android, background

Normally In an Fragment, implicit intent can be used to start a brower component,if there are several brower component, the Android system will show an selection dialog ,the dialog just overlay the Fragment which send the intent.

**but in my situation when selection dialog is shown ,the Fragment go to the background(disappeared) ,and the home screen can be seen.**

does anyone encounter this problem ,how to make the Fragment not go to the backgoround.

in onPause method it just look like below in my fragment source

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    mLog.printMethodLifeCycle("onPause");
    super.onPause();

}
```

and in activity I did not overide the onPause method

AndroidManifest.xml is too long ,can you tell me which part should I post or notice

Comment: how is your activity onPause() method look like? do you call finish() from onPause() or any other method of your activity or fragment> Is there any exception in the logcat? Also, post your AndroidManifest.xmnl here

Comment: Thank your hint , I correct the error , it did run finish() method in the activity which loaded the fragment.